# Suppress PluginResult Output in Phonegap 2.0.0

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am using Phonegap/Cordova 2.0.0 with the Contacts API.  When I make a find request, I receive a massive success output to the terminal with all the found contacts, beginning with:

> > PluginResult:toJSONString - {"status":1,"message":[{"id":

This output ends up being hundreds of lines.

Is there a way to toggle console output for Phonegap APIs?

UPDATE

Per comment below, this will be fixed in the next Phonegap Release.

Comment: What OS is this on? Sounds like a bug we should fix.

Comment: iPhone 4S running 5.1.1 (9B206)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shaz checked in code in 2.1 that will default to no logs but you can enable them again by calling setVerbose.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/commit/2979d14d70d5f5e67d0c42b81afab76964cdf048#CordovaLib/Classes/CDVPluginResult.m

Comment: Can I just copy this over the existing CordovaLib/Classes/CDVPluginResult .h and .m files, and recompile, or do I need to wait for 2.1?

Comment: I'd probably just wait for 2.1 as it'll be out on Sept 4th.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Due to this bug, the console tries to show long data, and technically freezes the app.

Why phonegap/cordova doesn't have alpha/beta phase?
Do we all have to be always beta testers??
Please try to release -stable- version for such as 2.0..